# How to integrate Wordpress and bbPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

Can anyone explain me how to integrate Wordpress 3.0.1 and the bbPress 1.0.I just want to install bbPress with my previous Wordpress site (Url : mysite.com).I just want to install it on mysite.com/forum .
I just tried doing it by creating a folder and installing bbPress there,( I skipped the wordpress integration ). When I tried to log onto the bbPress,it just throwed a hell lot of warnings saying function deprecated.
I can not figure out why this all is happening.Is this due to some version problem?

Answer (score 1):

You get those errors if you are running PHP 5.3+
It was fixed in the trunk but since then there are no bbPress releases. You can safely upgrade to trunk, its better than last version anyway.

Regarding integration follow this [integration guide](http://blog.ashfame.com/2009/07/integrate-bbpress-10-with-wordpress-28/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe function deprecated is an issue of WordPress/bbPress running some old code for compatibility with earlier versions of PHP. You can disable the `display_errors` in your [php configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), [server configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) or [WordPress configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

For information about integrating WordPress with bbPress, make sure you read the [documentation](http://bbpress.org/documentation/integration-with-wordpress/) and browse their forums. They've discussed this millions of times ;)

Cheers.